# Adding a query string to a link in Views

Tags: 7, views

I've added an "Add Comment Link" to a View and I'm wondering how I would go about adding a custom query string to the generated URL?

I'd guess I need to do something under "Rewrite Results", either with "Rewrite the output of this field" or "Output this field as a link" but I only seem to have an option to include the fully rendered link as a replacement token.

Is there a way (without resorting to regex) to get the URL from the link so I can rewrite the output myself? Or is there an easier way to add the query string?

Thanks

Comment: IF the link is field of view it could be possible to get the url in tpl using the $row variable.

Comment: @j2r: It is a field, but I guess there's nothing in the UI already to do this? That's not a problem as templates are fine for my purposes. If you want to post that as the answer I'll accept it, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the link is a field of view, it could be possible to get the URL in the template file using the `$row` variable.